# Implementing the Hadoop and MongoDB connector

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am working with Hadoop for the very first time, since I am planning to use it with MongoDB. After installing Hadoop, I tried to to follow this tutorial and implement its example http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/

Everything works until I call this command

```
bash examples/treasury_yield/run_job.sh
```

Then I get the following message

```
14/03/11 17:52:45 INFO util.MongoTool: Created a conf: 'Configuration: core-defa
ult.xml, core-site.xml, src/examples/hadoop-local.xml, src/examples/mongo-defaul
ts.xml' on {class com.mongodb.hadoop.examples.treasury.TreasuryYieldXMLConfig} a
s job named '<unnamed MongoTool job>'
14/03/11 17:52:46 INFO util.MongoTool: Mapper Class: class com.mongodb.hadoop.ex
amples.treasury.TreasuryYieldMapper
14/03/11 17:52:46 INFO util.MongoTool: Setting up and running MapReduce job in f
oreground, will wait for results.  {Verbose? true}
14/03/11 17:52:47 WARN fs.FileSystem: "localhost:9100" is a deprecated filesyste
m name. Use "hdfs://localhost:9100/" instead.
14/03/11 17:52:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop
.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-goncalopereira/mapre
d/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job_201403111752_0001/job.jar could only be re
plicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBloc
k(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.jav
a:736)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI
nvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat
ionHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock
(DFSClient.java:3686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStrea
m(DFSClient.java:3546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClien
t.java:2749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFS
Client.java:2989)

14/03/11 17:52:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanod
e[0] nodes == null
14/03/11 17:52:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source fil
e "/tmp/hadoop-goncalopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job_2014031
11752_0001/job.jar" - Aborting...
14/03/11 17:52:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://loc
alhost:9100/tmp/hadoop-goncalopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job
_201403111752_0001
14/03/11 17:52:47 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionExceptio
n as:goncalopereira cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOExcep
tion: File /tmp/hadoop-goncalopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job
_201403111752_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBloc
k(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.jav
a:736)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

14/03/11 17:52:47 ERROR util.MongoTool: Exception while executing job...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-gon
calopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job_201403111752_0001/job.jar
 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBloc
k(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.jav
a:736)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI
nvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat
ionHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock
(DFSClient.java:3686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStrea
m(DFSClient.java:3546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClien
t.java:2749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFS
Client.java:2989)
14/03/11 17:52:47 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /tmp/hadoop-goncalo
pereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job_201403111752_0001/job.jar
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-gon
calopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job_201403111752_0001/job.jar
 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBloc
k(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.jav
a:736)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI
nvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat
ionHandler.java:62)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock
(DFSClient.java:3686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStrea
m(DFSClient.java:3546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClien
t.java:2749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFS
Client.java:2989)
```

As you can guess this is a bit overwhelming to a newbie like me. I assume it's some problem with Hadoop but not entirely sure what. I really wish someone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you try to put a file into HDFS using the following command : hadoop fs -put local-file hdfs-path. If this gives an error then there would be a problem with HDFS setup. Also check your NameNode web UI to see if data nodes are listed. you can also run hadoop -fsck to check the filesystem health.

Comment: I guess datanodes is not up and running, what is output of jps command when you are running this job? do you see datanode in list?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to me not having a livenode. But it baffles on why, since I did all the steps correctly and I didn't get any message, I tried to restart the cluster and modify the config files but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have connected hadoop with mongodb using mongoDBConnector using this link

[hadoop connection with mongodb](http://www.frustrateddevelopers.com/2015/10/hadoop-connection-with-mongodb-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concentrate on this error:

`ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionExceptio
n as:goncalopereira cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOExcep
tion: File /tmp/hadoop-goncalopereira/mapred/staging/goncalopereira/.staging/job
_201403111752_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1`

1. Check if that jar is present on the path.
2. Check if you are starting you dataNode because it takes time to start.

Make sure your hadoop is installed correctly and try running a sample dataset just for hadoop without bringing MangoDB into picture. This will differentiate where things are going wrong. Hope it helps.

Comment: According to the web interface I have 0 live nodes. Tried to format again the HDFS and restart the clusters but the same thing happens.